# C# WPF Application - Show second window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to show another WPF window in my project, but it keeps giving me an error CS1061 (missing using directive). My code is representated below.

My project consists of two pages, one main, and one window that should open after the click.

The code of the click is where I get the error. 
It gives the error code showed before...

the click:

```
        }
        private void Win_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var form = new Window();
            form.ShowDialog();        //ERROR  CS1061
        }
```

I am using following Using-Directives:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

I also tried changing my click code to this, but I still get the same error:

```
        }
        private void Win_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var form = new Window();
            form.Show();        //ERROR  CS1061
        }
```

I hope you can help me finding the issue with my code snippet, why I keep getting that error.
Thanks for taking your time to help me!

Comment: Visual Studio usually suggests what dependency to add. Have you tried clicking the little yellow lightbulb on the left when you're on that line? Or hitting "Ctrl+."?

Comment: Do you have more compile errors?

Comment: @Sinatr no more, just this one error!

Comment: @Fildor yes I tried, it just suggests me to throw a new not implemented exception...

Comment: Try new System.Windows.Window(); instead of new Window(); and tell us whether that fixes your problem; If not, try to use a try/catch block and alert the stack trace in a MessageBox.

Comment: @TimB I don't think try/catch will help, since this should be a compile time error.

Comment: in fact, this did not help....

Comment: Can you give the full text of your compiler error message - the documentation says Error CS1061 is "This error occurs when you try to call a method or access a class member that does not exist"

Comment: @Fildor - sounded like it was a runtime exception occuring on click, but you're right - missing using directive exception happens at compile time. Patrick - You sure the click event code is the issue?

Comment: @TimB the form.Show is giving me the issue.... The error is in the keyowrd show / showdialog...

Comment: Your new window should be a specific window such as window1 or whatever rather than the generic base class.

Comment: I was able to reproduce same error if I have somewhere my own class `Window` defined. Using fully qualified type name `new System.Windows.Window()` (@TimB comment above) should help.

Comment: @Fildor in the Stack Exchange app? No, i don't know how to do that sorry.

Comment: Is this really a WPF application ? ...forms are winforms.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan `form` is just the name of the variable OP is using. `Window` is WPF, as are the System.Windows.* namespaces.

Comment: @PatrickDaRin Have you tried restarting VS and/or cleaning/rebuilding the solution? I've had weird problems like this before where VS decides to forget what basic classes are, and doing the above usually fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Did you really create a window and decide to call it Window? That would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a named WPF window, creating an instance of that window (instead of a generic window), then running that code after replacing the window with the named wpf window.

Edit: I would also set the owner of your new named WPF window according to what object "owns" it.

Comment: +1 for setting the owner. If you every have to write UI automation against a application that only sporadically sets the owner you will understand how frustrating this is.